# Facebook and Google+ button alignment stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, google-plus

The following Google+ and Facebook like buttons were perfectly aligned as of a few days ago.  I made no changes to the code whatsoever, but the buttons stopped being aligned, as I just noticed today.

The alignment is broken in all browsers, so I'm assuming that some changes have been made either to Google+, Facebook or jquery, which is the only code used on this page.

Can anyone tell what's wrong here?  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9h4R/)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="center" id="social">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <p class="center">Follow us!</p>
    <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Google" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
</div>

<script>
(function() {
    var buttonsToLoad = 2;
    $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js', function() {
        FB.init({appId:'277943145587768',status:true,cookie:true,xfbml:true});
        FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', onButtonLoaded);
    });
    $.getScript('https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js', function() {
        $('#___plusone_0 iframe').load(onButtonLoaded)
    });
    function onButtonLoaded() {
        buttonsToLoad--;
        if(buttonsToLoad === 0) {
            showButtonBlock();
        }
    }
    function showButtonBlock() {
        $('#social').animate({opacity : 1}, 1000);
    }
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. I can't speak for it fixing it consistently across multiple browsers.

`.fb-like { top: -4px; }`

Comment: Are you confirming that it's not aligned for you either (because another user reported that it looks fine in his browser)?

Comment: Ya, it not aligned for me on _Chrome 33.0.1750.70 beta_ or _Firefox 27.0_

Comment: Thanks.  But now I wonder if it's going to be out of alignment for the other user who reported it looked ok.  Also, it's now broken on iPhone and Nexus 7.  Still not sure how perfectly working code became broken overnight.

Comment: A combination of code changing (your's and third-party) and browsers changing make for an ever moving target.

Comment: I understand, just wondering who caused this, Facebook or Google.

Comment: By the way, how did you guess that it was exactly 4 pixels?

Comment: I eyeballed it. It actually looked like 4.5 pixels would be better but I didn't want to mess around further.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a lot of problems with alignment lately too ... mostly Facebook icons ... it appears they have changed the coding and appearance of their reference links ... their "like" and "follow" divs used to produce a dark blue box looking graphic and now they are lighter blue in color and more rounded ... I had to change alignment on some pages since I had just used the basic divs in tables ... I ended up adding CSS like suggested to control alignment for not only Facebook links but for the Linkedin, Twitter, and Google+ links too so if any of them change in the future I am hopefully covered without having to edit any pages.

Comment: That's true, but my code was written after Facebook switched to the new blue icon.  It's only a couple weeks old.

Comment: My guess is they are still "messing" with them ... the other night all my FB links were off to the right, and the next day they were aligned to the left ... frustrating to say the least!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the CSS for the Facebook button (HTML5 code) you will see that the first span after the div.fb-like wrapper has `vertical-align: bottom;` property. Google plus first rendered div has `vertical-align: baseline;` property.

Adding this to your CSS will solve the vertical alignment issue:

```
.fb-like > span {
  vertical-align: baseline !important;  
}
```

This should work cross-browsers.
There also could be an issue where the Facebook button has no right margin/spacing and is "glued" to the next button. Adding this or some margin-right can solve this issue (adapt the width to your design).

```
.fb-like {
  width: 120px; 
}
```

It seems the Facebook button does not follow Twitter and Google plus buttons implementation (anymore?).

Answer (score 0):

Add these classes to your css

```
.fb-like {display:block; float:left; margin-right:10px;}
.g-plusone {display:block;  float:left;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9h4R/1/)

Comment: They're supposed to be on the same line, so that won't work.  I am more interested in knowing why they were aligned before and suddenly became misaligned.

Comment: @KnocksX On the same line? They are on the same line...am I missing something?

Comment: As far as how they were, and are now, I see no declaration of styling on your end...they are mere iframes and google/fb may set the css on their end but if they change it for any reason, your stuck...you should declare your own styling for them always.

Comment: They are currently out of alignment on my screen.  The facebook button sits several pixels lower than the G+ button.  Is that not what you're seeing?

Comment: @KnocksX Not at all...I see perfect alignment. JSFiddle via Firefox.

Comment: That's crazy, this is what I see in both Chrome and Firefox: http://i.imgur.com/mpXG8t3.jpg

Comment: @KnocksX Woah :x  I can't help you then :/

Comment: But you can at least confirm that they're not aligned in my screenshot so I know I'm not going blind? :)

Comment: Thanks.  The other user reported it out of alignment in his browser, so we shifted the Facebook button by 4 pixels.  Can you check how it's looking now on your machine?

Comment: @KnocksX Do you have a jsfiddle link to send me, I'll take a look :)

Comment: @KnocksX Looks perfect man! I was expecting otherwise but I'm glad its spot on! Looks good in Safari as well :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the script, I use embedded links so I can control their alignment:

SCRIPT:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&#038;appId=50093919333";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

EMBEDS:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://anaconda-development.com" data-send="true" data-height="20" data-width="280" data-show-faces="false" data-font="tahoma" style="height: 20px" ></div>
<div class="fb-follow" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/anacondadevelopment" data-show-faces="false" data-font="tahoma" data-width="280" data-height="20" style="height: 20px" ></div>
```